# How to Unit Test handling of incoming Jersey MultiPart requests

Tags: java, rest, testing, jersey, multipart

We have a **REST** service that accepts `MultiPart` **POST** requests containing `BodyParts` that hold `InputStream`s. Inside the REST service a **file** might be created based on the provided data.

### Task

We want to unit test the class that does the file operations based on its `MultiPart` input. **Note**: Wo do NOT want to use Jersey-Test! Grizzly does not load our spring application context which we need to inject DAO and fileHandler services into our REST service class. We explicitly want to test how our fileHandler service processes multiPart data.

The problem however is that the `MultiPart` that is sent out from the **REST Client** is not the same as the one received by the **REST Server** as jersey probably does something with the data to stream it or whatever. Trying to test (see below) the following setup will result in an

```
IllegalArgumentException [B cannot be cast to com.sun.jersey.multipart.BodyPartEntity
```

### REST Client - sending a MultiPart

(just snippets, I omitted the obvious stuff):

```
    byte[] bytes = FileManager.readImageFileToArray(completePath, fileType);

    MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart().
            bodyPart(new BodyPart(bytes, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE)).
            bodyPart(new BodyPart(fileName, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)).
            bodyPart(new BodyPart(senderId, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE));

    ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
    cc.getClasses().add(MultiPartWriter.class);
    Client client = Client.create(cc);
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(requestUrl);
    Builder builder = webResource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);
    builder = addHeaderParams(builder, headerParams);

    ClientResponse response = builder.post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart);
```

### Server Side - receiving a MultiPart

REST:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Transactional
public Response create(MultiPart multiPart) {

    try {
            multiPartReader.saveFile(multiPart);
```

Server Side MultiPartReader to save file from multipart

```
public class MultiPartReader {

    public void saveFile(MultiPart multiPart) throws IOException {

        BodyPartEntity bpe = (BodyPartEntity) multiPart.getBodyParts().get(0).getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = bpe.getInputStream();

        // ...

        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
        String fileName = getFileNameFromMultiPart(multiPart);

        File file = new File(filename);

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            ImageIO.write(bi, formatName, file);
        } else {
            file.mkdirs();
            ImageIO.write(bi, formatName, file);
        }

        bpe.close();
    }
```

### Test - handling an incoming MultiPart in isolation

Now I want to test the MultiPartReader:

```
@Test
public void saveFile_should_Create_file() throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileResource));

    MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart().
            bodyPart(new BodyPart(bytes, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE)).
            bodyPart(new BodyPart(fileName, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)).
            bodyPart(new BodyPart(senderId, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE));
     
    multiPartReader.saveFile(multiPart);

    file = new File(fileName);
    Assert.assertNotNull(file);
    Assert.assertTrue(file.getTotalSpace() > 0);
    file.delete();
}
```

But, like I said I get a

```
IllegalArgumentException [B cannot be cast to com.sun.jersey.multipart.BodyPartEntity
```

at

```
    BodyPartEntity bpe = (BodyPartEntity) multiPart.getBodyParts().get(0).getEntity();
```

**So what can I do to emulate the send/receive handled by jersey so that my test will get the same data as my REST service does deployed on a server and requested by a REST client?**

### EDIT

Using

```
BodyPartEntity bpe = multiPart.getBodyParts().get(0).getEntityAs(BodyPartEntity.class);
```

will throw a

```
IllegalStateException: Entity instance does not contain the unconverted content
```

Further pointer, I think, towards having to convert the test-generated MultiPart in some way, before calling my MultiPartReader..

There has to be some method in jersey, I can call that will do this converting just the way it does, when it sends out a MultiPart request on a deployed system or maybe it is the receiving end that does some parsing when receiving the HTTP request..?

Comment: Hi, similar situation. Did you find any workaround ?

Comment: Nope, never found it, though admitedly we just stopped looking and skip those tests.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [jersey-multipart](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/contribs/jersey-multipart/index.html?com/sun/jersey/multipart/BodyPart.html) docs I see:

"It is not currently possible to know ahead of time what Java class the application would prefer to use for each individual body part, so an appropriate Provider cannot be selected. Currently, the unparsed content of each body part is returned (as a byte array) in the entity property of the returned BodyPart} instance, and the application can decide what further steps are needed based on the headers included in that body part. The simplest technique is to examine the received BodyPart, and then call the getEntityAs() method once you know which implementation class you would prefer."

It looks like you need to follow that suggestion.  Examine the byte array returned in your Server Side MultiPartReader code:

```
multiPart.getBodyParts().get(0).getEntity();
```

...and call getEntityAs() on the BodyPart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm quite happy with the server side, as it is working as intended when deployed to a server and accessed via actual REST calls from a client application. using getEntityAs() in this circumstance makes no difference. What I want to know is how I can setup a MultiPart in my test so that it looks like the data that the service well receive in reality. Both my test and my client use the same methods to setup the MultiPart data but the test fails where the live system succeeds. How can I emulate the parsing or marshalling or whatever done by jersey?

Comment: BTW: When I use getEntityAs() on the server side and then run my tests it will tell me: `IllegalStateException: Entity instance does not contain the unconverted content`

Comment: Did you find any workaround for setting up MultiPart data for Junit Test case?

Comment: Scratching my head over this issue for unit test right now. I know it's an old issue. But any more info guys?